# Navigation bar button image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using this code to get a logo on my nav bar.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let image = UIImage(named: "LogoWithTextSmaller.png")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
```

This is fine, but the logo doesn't have any colour - besides 'blue'. Is it because it is a png file. Is there something I can so it retains the original colours

I have done this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

and that brings the image onto the nav bar with the correct colours - but it's in the middle and I want it on the left.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Tintcolor?     UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: I already have a background colour on the NAV bar, the image is transparent and that is a light blue and green colour but when i add it in with leftBarButtonItem it goes a dull blue. When I use titleview to show the image - its fine but i need to get that to the left and not in the middle.

Comment: Have you tried this: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: Yes, the colour changes, but the colour is in the png file and not on iOS :( so it doesn't work because the colours are not correct - there are multiple colours in the png.

Answer (score 33):

You need to declare that the image stays original all the time. so add the code as below

```
var image = UIImage(named: "image-name")
image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style:.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: @bhavik shah thanks this works great. The only issue. The image used needs to be really small to fit in the navbar and then looks pixelated, especially on 6 and 6 plus. Is there aa way we can use a big image but set a frame to make it fit in the nav bar?

Comment: You can actually achieve that with single line: `someBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "yourPictureName")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)`

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 3** the same would be accomplished using the following syntax

```
var image = UIImage(named: "Filter")
image = image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:image , style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let btnLogo = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
btnLogo.setTitle("", for: .normal)
btnLogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
btnLogo.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
btnLogo.layer.masksToBounds = true

var imageLogo = UIImage(named: "LogoWithTextSmaller.png")
imageLogo = imageLogo?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
btnLogo.setImage(imageLogo, for: .normal)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLogo)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

**swift 2.0**

```
var image = UIImage(named: "Filter")
image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
```

**Objective-C**

```
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

 UIBarButtonItem *_btnLeftBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LogoWithTextSmaller.png"]
                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                     target:self
                                                     action:@selector(yourMethod)];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem= _btnLeftBar;
```

For withRenderingMode(_:) details see below apple documentation link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624153-withrenderingmode

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4**

```
    let back = UIImage(named: "back_white")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: back, style:.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In swift 3.0**

```
    let Navigateimage = UIImage(named: "LogoWithTextSmaller.png")
    Navigateimage = Navigateimage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: Navigateimage, style:.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 3***
If the item is missing, you can try this.

```
  let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
  let topItem = navigationBar?.topItem
  var navigateimage = UIImage(named: "addConnectionFromSupport")
  navigateimage = navigateimage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
  topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: navigateimage, style:.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```